# In Python, why isn't the nth root of the nth power of a number equal to the number itself?

Tags: python, exponentiation, nth-root

I noticed that when I potentiate some numbers in Python, they are not the same after the inverse operation (root), for example:

```py
>>> n = 28108234917303648763818746285031
>>> m = (n ** 5) ** (1 / 5)
>>> n == int(m)
False
>>> print(f'{m:.0f}')
28108234917303762475100368011264
```

Using `math.pow(n ** 5, 1 / 5)` yields the same result. Any ideas on why? I'd also appreciate a solution to make this consistent in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you exponentiate an integer to power which is a positive integer, the result is also an integer which in python has arbitrary precision.
However, when you raise it to a non-integer power (like `1/5`), the base and the result will be coerced a floating point number which has limited precision, leading to the error you see here.

```
>>> n = 28108234917303648763818746285031
>>> type(n ** 5)
<class 'int'>
>>> type((n ** 5) ** (1 / 5))
<class 'float'>
>>> (n ** 5) ** (1 / 5) == (float(n ** 5)) ** (1 / 5)
True
```

Comment: Could also use `import math; math.isclose(m, n)`... to get a positive result in this case but ultimately... just try to not have to do that...

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I thought floating point numbers also had arbitrary precision in Python.

Comment: @CaioJoca: With the built-in `float` type, unfortunately not. From the documentation: "You are at the mercy of the underlying machine architecture"